# "Influence Layout" in Alloy

Tags: alloy, graph-layout

When defining a theme for the Alloy Visualizer, there is the option for a relation to "Influence Layout". Normally, when `p->q` is an edge in the relation `r`, the layout places `p` above `q`, with the `r`-edge pointing downwards. I would expect that turning off "Influence Layout" for `r` would allow `p` and `q` to occupy the same level in the graph, so that the `r`-edge could point horizontally. But this never happens. Indeed, I have never observed the "Influence Layout" checkmark to have any effect at all. What does it do?